# Add more input to YUI POST CONNECTION

Tags: post, connection, yui

can some one help me please.
how can I add 1 more input to YUI POST CONNECTION
Here is the tutorial: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/connection/post.html
And the default sample form is: `<form><input type="button" value="Send a POST Request" onClick="makeRequest();"></form>`

How can I add one more input like that:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="button" value="Send a POST Request" onClick="makeRequest();">
</form>
```

I want to send username input request too.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

The example you reference builds the POST request body manually.  While you can certainly do this, you might find it easier to use the [setForm](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Connect.html#method_setForm) method of the Connection Manager ([example here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/#forms)).  It will include all the form fields and take care of the URL encoding for you.